# IndexError from for loop

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, index-error

I've had errors like this before, but I typically get them when doing a range and not enumerate. Sorry if this is a stupid error, I just can't make sense of it.
This is the code leading up to where the error occurs:

```
maxtemp = 320
temperaturelist = range(10, maxtemp + 1,10)  #this goes from 10 to 320 ins steps of 10
numtemps = np.asarray(temperaturelist).size

#read in actual spectral data, and display
spectraldataactualgrid_values = np.empty((numtemps, 201)) 
spectraldatapoints = np.empty([6432,2])             
spectraldatavalues = np.empty(6432) 

count=0
for i, temperature in enumerate(temperaturelist): 
    wavelengthvector, intensityvector = loadspec(temperature)
    for j, wavelength in enumerate(wavelengthvector):
        spectraldatapoints[count] = [temperature, wavelength]
        spectraldatavalues[count] = intensityvector[j] 
        spectraldataactualgrid_values[i, j] = intensityvector[j]
        count+=1

#loadspec comes from a previous definition where I load in my spectral data
```

Error Message:

```
IndexError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-6f2072c90554> in <module>()
 77         spectraldatapoints[count] = [temperature, wavelength]
 78         spectraldatavalues[count] = intensityvector[j]
---> 79         spectraldataactualgrid_values[i, j] = intensityvector[j]
 80         count+=1
 81 # plt.figure(1)

IndexError: index 201 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 201
```

EDIT****
So for that previous error, I figured out that I had to switch the 201 in spectraldataactualgrid_values to 2415 (the size of intensity vector). However, now the error is:

```
IndexError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-d0f8f1371388> in <module>()
     56 #     #print(len(wavelengthvector))
     57     for j, wavelength in enumerate(wavelengthvector):
---> 58         spectraldatapoints[count] = [temperature, wavelength]
     59 
     60         spectraldatavalues[count] = intensityvector[j]

IndexError: index 6432 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 6432
```

So I have a number wrong somewhere I'm guessing.

Comment: spectraldataactualgrid_values = np.empty((numtemps, 201)) 
why 201 ?
what is the length of temperaturelist and wavelengthvector

Comment: The length of the temperaturelist is 32, but that's what the numtemps size is. The length of the wavelengthvector is 2415. I'm not sure what the reasoning for the 201 is. I just picked up this code from a previous student's work and am trying to get to a point where I'll eventually interpolate the data (hopefully).

Comment: Could you try adding `print(spectraldataactualgrid_values[i,j])` and `print(intensityvector[j])` above line 79 to see which array is causing the IndexError?

Comment: For the first error, it was for the intensityvector (I just figured it our), but now I'm getting a similar error for the spectraldatapoints[count] line. Whenever I print out it's length, I get 6432, but I'm not sure what number it should be that it's causing this error...